# Validation using DeleteView before deleting instance

Tags: django, django-forms

What's the best approach for handling deletion of an object with some validation before the object is deleted?  For example, in my setup have two models - `Game` and `Team` (which are obviously related).  Users should only be able to delete teams that are NOT tied to any games.

I created a form (without any fields) for deleting a team...

```
class TeamDeleteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = []

    def clean(self):
        # Check to see if this team is tied to any existing games
        if self.instance.gameteams_set.exists():
            raise ValidationError("This team is tied to 1 or more games")
        return super().clean()
```

But then I realized that the class based view DeleteView doesn't have any sort of form_valid() method.  Should I extend the generic FormView instead of DeleteView or is there a better approach that I'm missing?

Comment: Did you take a look at my answer below?

Comment: @SimonCharette I did, thanks.  However, I think I have a better solution using FormView.  Still not ideal, and I'm waiting to see if anyone else is going to answer before I post my solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the best approach will be overriding the model's delete method. For example:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    ...
    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if Game.objects.filter(team__pk= self.pk).exists():
            raise Exception('This team is related to a game.')  # or you can throw your custom exception here.
        super(Team, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: How can this be the accepted solution? This will result in an error 500 since you're raising an unhandled exception...

Comment: Agreed, I think the answer @Esteban gave is the best. It answers the question most directly.

Comment: For a better user experience you could return HttpResponseForbidden() instead of raise Exception()

Comment: no longer works in Django 4.2

Answer (score 10):

For your particular case I would simply override the `queryset` attribute of your view to exclude `Team`s with associated `Game`s.

```python
class TeamDeleteView(DeleteView):
    queryset = Team.objects.distinct().exclude(games__isnull=False)
```

There's a [Django ticket opened to make the `DeleteView` behave like other form views](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21936) but until [the proposed patch](https://github.com/django/django/pull/2585) is merged and released (It won't make it in 1.8) you'll have to completely override the `delete` method of your view like the following:

```python
class TeamDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Team

    def delete(request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if self.object.gameteams_set.exists():
            # Return the appropriate response
        success_url = self.get_success_url()
        self.object.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
```

Edit:

From your accepted solution it looks like you're trying to prevent deletion at the model level. Such enforcement should be done by using a `PROTECT` [`on_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) handler.

```
from django.db import models

class Team(models.Model):
    pass

class Game(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

You'll still have to deal with the raised `ProtectedError` in your view:

```
from django.db import models
from django.http.response import HttpResponseForbidden

class TeamDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Team

    def delete(request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super(TeamDeleteView, self).delete(
                request, *args, **kwargs
            )
        except models.ProtectedError as e:
            # Return the appropriate response
            return HttpResponseForbidden(
                "This team is tied to 1 or more games"
            )
```

You could even use the `protected_objects` property of `e` to display a more meaningful error message just like the admin does.

Comment: What if you want to do this with Django's Admin?

Comment: Django's admin automatically deals with these errors in [1.10+](https://github.com/django/django/commit/a7c813ba045044ec23bb656ef9a23a0e38e36514) but you could override your `ModelAdmin` subclass's `delete_selected` method in similar way if you can't use this version.

Answer (score 7):

I've used both DeleteView and FormView for this scenario. Both have their pros and cons.

DeleteView is nice because it's based on the SingleObjectMixin and you can easily get access to the object you want to delete. One nice way of doing this is raising an exception in get_object. This makes it so that you can raise exception on both get and post.

```
def get_object(self, qs):
  obj = super(FooView, self).get_object(qs)
  if obj.can_delete():
    return obj
  raise PermissionDenied
```

FormView is nice because you can leverage form_invalid and the clean methods, but then you still have to do the work to get the object, setup some sort of form (not needed in deleteview).

It's really a matter of how you want to tackle it. Some other questions are: do you raise an exception on GET, or do you want to show a nice page letting the user know they can't delete the object. This can be done in both View types.

Update your question if you have more points to go over and i'll update my response.

Answer (score 1):

One other way to do it would be to work with django.db IntegrityError!

```
from django.db import IntegrityError

class TeamDeleteView(DeleteView):
model = Team

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """If DB Integrity Error, display msg and redirect to list"""
        try:
            return(super().delete(request, *args, **kwargs))
        except IntegrityError:
            messages.error(request, "This team is tied to 1 or more games")
            return render(request, template_name=self.template_name, context=self.get_context_data())
```

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the model's delete method (most of the answers here do that) does not work anymore in Django 4.0.

> In accordance with `FormMixin`, object deletion for POST requests is
> handled in `form_valid()`. Custom delete logic in `delete()` handlers
> should be moved to `form_valid()`, or a shared helper method, as needed.

There is also a discussion [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33263).